# how angular directive bind controller's service data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

```js
controller:
service.checkSub(function(data){
  $scope.showSub = data.subscribe? false : true;
})

directive:
app.directive('showSub', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            showSub: '=show'
        },
        templateUrl: '<div data-ng-show="show">test</div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.showSub); // undifined
            if(scope.showSub) {
                scope.show = true;
            }else {
                scope.show = false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<show-sub show="showSub"></show-sub>
```

why the **scope.showSub** in directive is **undefined** ,and I want to use it to control the directive? how should I do it?

Comment: It should be `template` instead of `templateUrl`, no?

Comment: What is `service` inside the controller? Is it an angularjs service? What is the purpose of the `checkSub` function? Is it a function of the `service`?

Comment: try giving value in the parent controller of the directive like **$scope.showSub = true;** you will get that value in directive console.log(scope.showSub). so, your directive is fine problem with the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `scope.showSub` gives undefined, because when loading in the directive, the `showSub` of your controller scope isn't filled yet. What you can do to fix it:

- Change `templateUrl` to `template`
- Change `ng-show="show"` to `ng-show="showSub"`
- Lose the `link` function (it is not needed, as you can directly bind to the scope variables in your template)

code:

```
app.directive('showSub', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            showSub: '=show'
        },
        template: '<div data-ng-show="showSub">test</div>',
        link: function(scope, elem) {
            // this function isn't needed, but to show you it gives undefined due to the async call
            console.log(scope.showSub); // undefined
            $timeout(function(){
                console.log(scope.showSub); // true
            }, 1500);
        }
    }
});
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d0wv9xa5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your directive is fine but problem with the service.

```
service.checkSub(function(data){
  $scope.showSub = data.subscribe? false : true;
})
```

**$scope.showSub** should be in parent scope.

make sure you have data in $scope.showSub

Answer (score 0):

You can get value of showSub by scope.$parent.showSub

So your code will be like ..

```
  app.directive('showSub', function() {
   return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        showSub: '=show'
    },
    templateUrl: '<div data-ng-show="show">test</div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log(scope.$parent.showSub); 
        if(scope.$parent.showSub) {
            scope.show = true;
        }else {
            scope.show = false;
        }
    }
  }
});
```